How can i translate the AltBeacons-reference-app to JetPack Compose?
I want to translate the reference app from Altbeaconse (https://github.com/davidgyoung/android-beacon-library-reference-kotlin) to JetPack Compose, has someone used this library with JetPack Compose before?
I have tried to create my own ViewModel but the library have already one so i don't know how to translate it

The library's Kotlin reference app is a few years old and predates Jetpack Compose as the recommended Android UI paradigm.  Unfortunately there has been no work to date converting it to use Jetpack Compose.
The Android Beacon Library is an open source project and ecourages contributions.  Anyone interested in working on such a variant is welcome to do so.  This has not been done so far largely because, as the lead developer on the project, my skills with Jetpack Compose are still pretty rough, making it a bit time consuming.
The library's BeaconManager does support a ViewModel for beacon ranging and monitoring allowing LiveData observers for beacon detection updates.  This may make it easier to integrate data binding with composable UIs.  The documentation shows how to do that in an Activity (in a UI-independent way) here https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html

I'm afraid I'm going to have to do it. If you want to help me, it will be a pleasure!
